# How stop triggering event from base src/App.vue?

Tags: vuejs2

In vue/cli 4 application
In src/App.vue I have method for retrieving data from server like :

```
mounted() {
    retrieveAppDictionaries(['copyright_text', 'site_heading', 'site_name']);
    bus.$on('appDictionariesRetrieved', (data) => {
        this.copyright_text = data.copyright_text
        this.site_heading = data.site_heading
        this.site_name = data.site_name
    })
}, // mounted() {
```

In one of the pages I have similar method for retrieving data from server, but with different parameters, like :

```
mounted() {
    retrieveAppDictionaries(['userTaskTypesLabels']);
    bus.$on('appDictionariesRetrieved', (data) => {
        this.userTaskTypesLabels = data.userTaskTypesLabels
    })

}, // mounted() {
```

The problem is that in the second case appDictionariesRetrieved from src/App.vue is also triggered, what is wrong. 
How stop triggering appDictionariesRetrieved from src/App.vue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a listener:

```
bus.$on('appDictionariesRetrieved')
```

You're basically creating 2 listeners, so they both do the work when they receive the message.

Do this instead:

- Put all the data in store so it can be accessed from 1 component
- Create this listener in just 1 component (in `App.vue`)
- Send that listener messages with needed data

### App.vue

```
mounted() {
  bus.$on('appDictionariesRetrieved', (data) => {
    this.handleRetrieveAppDictionaries(data)
  })
},
methods: {
  handleRetrieveAppDictionaries(data) {
    // Get needed data 
    retrieveAppDictionaries(data.list)

    // Do some work
    if (data.purpose === "purpose1") {
      this.copyright_text = data.copyright_text
      this.site_heading = data.site_heading
      this.site_name = data.site_name
    }
    else if (data.purpose === "purpose2") {
      this.userTaskTypesLabels = data.userTaskTypesLabels
    }
  }
}
```

You can specify the data for that listener dynamically when you emit it, depending on where it's coming from:

```
let data = {
  copyright_text: '',
  site_heading: '',
  site_name: '',
  purpose: 'purpose1',
  list: ['copyright_text', 'site_heading', 'site_name']
  
}
bus.$emit('appDictionariesRetrieved', data)
```

Comment: 1) I dislike idea of keeping all data in store(app has vuex). My store keeps logged user info. We need data for userTaskTypesLabels
only if some specific page is opened. Why to retrieve it for a page which is not even opened?
2) What is data.purpose in your code ? Some kind of key send to server and returned back from server to be read when we need it ?

Comment: Well, if you don't want to have the listener in 1 component, just create it in each component but still use that `if` statement there so that all these listeners you will create don't run at once, just the one you need. That `purpose` property is for that `if` statement inside the listener handler, so that it runs only the `if` branch that you tell it to run

Answer (score 2):

```
export default {
 beforeDestroy() { // just before a component is destroyed.
  bus.$off('appDictionariesRetrieved') // stop listening.
 }
}
```

Assuming you are using an event bus you must have created a new Vue instance for it. If we emit an event within a component it stops listening to the event when the component is destroyed. But, in this case, the Vue instance is never destroyed, so the listener is always there.

> So, it's a good practice to stop listening to the events when a
>   component is destroyed to avoid conflict as in your case.